# jQuery .CSS not updating background

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to change a grid of small square divs to a random background color.
As far as I can tell my syntax is correct and the console is not throwing any errors but it's like the .css() will not accept my genColor method.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19437316/jquery-failing-to-update-background-color-css) which is very similar but the solution offered has not seemed to work.

```
function genColor() {
'use strict';
var hexes = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
var color = '#';

for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    color += hexes[Math.floor(Math.random * 16)];
}//end for loop

return color;
```

which is used in this

```
function highlightSquare() {
'use strict';

$('.square').on('mouseenter', function () {
    $(this).css('background', genColor()); 
});
```

Please help I can't figure out why this isn't working when examples show me it should.

P.S. The 'use strict'; keeps the Brackets editor JSLint from yelling at me. As near as I can tell it does not affect the code above.

Comment: Is the event firing? Add `alert(color);` right before the return to ensure it's running and generating a valid color. From what it looks like, your event listener is within the highlightSquare function - where it should probably not be within a function (aside from `$(document).load(function(){ });`).

Comment: "#undefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefined" - looks like i found OPs problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the issue is with `Math.random`, which is a function, so it should be `Math.random()`. Also, not sure from your code, but the event listener should be assigned outside of a function.

```
function genColor() {
  'use strict';
  var hexes = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    color += hexes[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }//end for loop
  return color;
}

$('.square').on('mouseenter', function () {
  $(this).css('background', genColor()); 
});
```

Here's a working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/fb15L86u/

Comment: son of a... I was like what's going on here...nice catch

Comment: Wow... I feel incredibly dumb for missing that. Thank you. But can you explain why the event listener should be outside the function? I was intending it to be resusable inclusive of the mouseenter?

Comment: @JScharfenberger - Technically you could put it inside a function, and ensure the function is called in your code prior to needing the event attached; but it's easier to tell when it is being listened to if it's just setup from the get-go. If you have a control on the page that determines whether the squares will be colored on hover (turning on coloring squares), you could just evaluate whether that control is enabled in your event listener - that way there's no binding or un-binding the event if you need it turned off.